# Cannot add text to <p>

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to insert some text after the first

tag:

```
<body id="tinymce" spellcheck="false">
   <p>
       // I want to insert text here
       <br>
   </p>
</body>
```

My attempt so far hasn't worked:

```
IElement tinymice;
string testText = "some text here"

string xPath = string.Format("//body[@id='{0}']/p", "tinymce");
tinymice = GetElementByXPath(xPath);

tinymce.SendKeys(string.Format("{0}", testText ));
```

Comment: last line --> is `tinymce` a typo?

Comment: no it's an id, do you see it?

Comment: @MSSucks Were you able to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Put the text into a span.  Paragraph tags are intended to be seperators.

Comment: yea but HOW...how do you append anything to a <p> tag through Selenium!??  I'm not asking for HTML semantics.  I'm asking how you append text to elements using Selenium once you have focus on that IWebElement.  I know you can GRAB text from an element with the text() attribute in XPath but I'm trying to use Selenium's Framework, specifically the IWebElement to APPEND text or data to an element.  I'm doing this because I'm testing form entry and entering data into the tinymce box it's just added to that tinymce body.  This is in an IFrame (also retarded); I have no say on that, our UX guy does.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs here: http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/jwebunit/api/IElement.html

I infer that you can call:

```
tinymice.setTextContent("text to insert");
```

I googled `"getelementbyxpath selenium"` I hope these are the right docs, it does list selenium at the bottom of the page: http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/jwebunit/api/class-use/IElement.html

I realize this is probably a javascript package, but this may be the same methods for the C# dll as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the above person was aware that tinyMCE is tinyMCE and not Tiny Mice..

Comment: But I would try  
Command: runScript
Target: tinyMCE.get('text_area_id').setContent('Your text here')
           
It's much more specific than using tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('Text here')